# Sequence contains no elements - DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

My sample works great on my Wifi internet at home. However, at work we have a proxy server and it is not working at all.

I enabled the default proxy and still not working. The "CreateRequest" call throws the exception:

**Sequence contains no elements**

Any idea? Thanks

---

I enabled logging and no file is being generated. What do you want me to do?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

[Activate logging](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/loggingdebugging-dotnetopenauth-with-log4net/) and see what it tells you.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I will try it at the office and come back with logs!

Thanks

Comment: Hi Andrew, shall I just paste the exception details or what exactly you want me to paste? Thanks